# Using WordPress shortcodes when <?php echo getPageContent(); ?> is used to display content

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, shortcode

I am working on a single page site where I am displaying content from other pages on this single page.  To do this I added a function that allows me to use `<?php echo getPageContent(ID); ?>` this is working fine except when I need to display content from a shortcode it just spits back the code as text instead. Any idea of a work around?

Answer (score 4):

To get the correct formatting and to have shortcodes replaced you need to apply the filters hooked into the `the_content` tag, something like this:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', getPageContent(ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you've chosen this strategy to display the content? Using something more in line with the normal wordpress page development and templating system will likely fix your problem. I recommend using a combination of get_posts() and setup_postdata()

From WordPress' docs:

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post;
?>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts